# jQuery UI buttonset() Not Responding As It Should?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I'm a newbie to the jQuery UI plugin and I'm building a demo application to test my knowledge. I'm using the [radio button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) add-on and I can't seem to get it working. I have the following line in a function called when the `body` loads:

```
$("#buttonSetDiv").buttonset();
```

I'm also including the CSS and JS correctly, like so:

```
<style src="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
```

... and the actual HTML looks like this:

```
<form name="radios" id="myForm">
<div id="buttonSetDiv">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="posts" id="radio1" checked onchange="valueChanged()"> <label for="radio1">Posts</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="members" onchange="valueChanged()" id="radio2">
<label for="radio2">Members</label>
</div>
</form>
```

... but for some reason, with this *seemingly* correct implementation, I'm still getting normal-looking radio buttons. I'd like to achieve this effect:

[image: picture]

Does anyone have an answer here? Thanks a ton in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<input>` is missing a closing quote on the `id="radio2"`, so this:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="members" onchange="valueChanged()" id="radio2>
```

Should be:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="members" onchange="valueChanged()" id="radio2">
```

This is throwing off at least Chrome in recognizing it correctly, [you can try the fixed version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/q3jMt/).

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, it's not actually in my code. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @seanny94 - Have you double checked your CSS path, you can get navigate to it in your browser fine?....and no errors in your console?

Comment: Hmm... I noticed that the jQueryUI stylesheet wasn't showing up under Chrome's Developer Tools (`Resources > Stylesheets` tab). So I changed the `<script src="...` tag to a `<LINK rel="...` to no avail... anything else you might have up your sleeve?

Comment: @seanny94 - Does it look like this now? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css">`  Also in chrome resources can you see the `.css`'s content?  Usually errors arise in cases like this from an incorrect path to the CSS.

Comment: D'oh! I was using `src="...` instead of `href="...` THANKS!